# How can I delete the Windows.old directory?

Tags: cmd, windows-10, corrupt

I've been trying to delete this extremely stubborn folder and nothing seems to work. First I tried the disk cleanup tool in the windows control panel, then CCleaner, and finally followed by a barrage of cmd tricks. I think one of the sub-files located under System32 is corrupt, because when I go to delete it normally I get the "The system could not find the specified item..." error. I even tried taking ownership of all files and folders within Windows.old, but was STILL denied access! Please help![image: ![Access denied.]

Comment: Well, I managed to finally delete everything except nvlddmkm.sys anything I throw at it says it's in use, but I can still do things like rename or move it. Does anyone know how to delete it?

Comment: This is answered here https://superuser.com/a/1752529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple to remove:

- Click in Windows' search field, type Cleanup, then click Disk Cleanup.
- Click the "Clean up system files" button.
- Wait a bit while Windows scans for files, then scroll down the list until you see "Previous Windows installation(s)."
- Select Previous Windows installation and anything else you want to remove and select OK.

If you've made all these attempts to remove it already though, you may have broken Windows ability to remove the folder.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I gave it another go, but had no luck.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting since?

Comment: Just did. Still trying to get rid of nvlddmkm.sys...

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli The file according to a quick google search is a left over of an Nvidia Driver. I would try to uninstally the driver so that you are only left over with the on-board graphics of your mainboard. Then restart your device (display output on VGA usually when using a Desktop-PC) in safe mode. This makes sure that only the onboard-graphis are used and not probably an external graphics card. Try to remove the file now. As the Nvidia drivers are no longer in use, the file should not be either. Then restart your device and reinstall the drivers. That would be my way to go.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I don't really understand why you should need to click the "Clean up system files" button first. But hey, thanks for that Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Answer for Windows 11 Users: This is answered here superuser.com/a/1752529